# C++ That Is Plaguing Me To This Day

Tags: c++, fstream, ifstream, ofstream

What is the correct solution?
What is the correct solution?
What is the correct solution?

**My Code (which is obviously wrong):**

`<iostream>` and `<fstream>` libraries are included.

```
int main() {

    int num = 0;
    int totalCount = 0;
    std::ifstream inFile;
    double average = 0.0;
    int totalTwo = 0;
    double total = 0.0;
    const double VALUE_ONE = 858.5;

    std::cout << "What is the number?  ";
    std::cin >> num;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    inFile.open("numbers.txt");
    while (inFile >> num) {

        totalCount += num;
    }

    total =  num * VALUE_ONE;
    average = total/totalCount;
    totalTwo = total * num;

   

    inFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

numbers.txt

Answer (score 2):

When you do this:

```
std::cin >> num;
std::cout << std::endl;

inFile.open("numbers.txt");
while (inFile >> num) {

    totalCount += num;
}
```

you're reading into `num` and then immediately overwriting it with data from the input file. Use two variables for the two inputs.

Comment: What two inputs? What is the 2nd input?

Comment: You're reading one number from standard input (`cin`), and you're reading a sequence of numbers from the file, but you're storing them into the same variable, before you use one of them.

Comment: Oh ok. Do you happen to know the math for calculations (For total, average,  and totalTwo?)

Comment: @OzzyTheBossy see my answer for that.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't really match what the instructions say to do.

You are reading the user's chosen multiplier into `num`, and then you are reading the numbers from the text file into `num` as well, losing the multiplier.  And you are not keeping track of how many numbers are read from the file, which you need in order to calculate the `average`.

You need to add a few more variables to your code to separate things.  Also, there is no need for your `VALUE_ONE` constant at all.

Try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    int multiplier = 0;
    int total = 0, totalTwo = 0;
    int quantity = 0;
    int num = 0;
    double average = 0.0;

    std::cout << "After all numbers are read, what number would you like to multiply the total by?  ";
    std::cin >> multiplier;
    std::cout << std::endl;

    std::ifstream inFile("numbers.txt");

    while (inFile >> num) {
        total += num;
        ++quantity;
    }

    inFile.close();

    average = double(total) / quantity;
    totalTwo = total * multiplier;

    std::cout << "Total = " << total << "\n" << "Average = " << average << "\n" << "Total * " << multiplier << " = " << totalTwo;

    return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/XONJ3q)